# why can't we compare two strings directly in c

Tags: c

why can't we compare two strings in c program directly.For example i have tried the following example

```
char *str="int";
if(str=="int")
printf("yes");
else
printf("no");
```

For the above I got output as **"no"**
I have tried the above code by using the same logic as if for integers
ie

```
int i=10;
if(i==10)
printf("same");
```

But when I have modified the above code like the following

```
if((strcmp(str,"int"))==0)
printf("yes");
```

I got the output as **"yes"**
What is the problem in the first stated code?

Comment: a char pointer is not an int

Comment: An advice: before asking here try to find the answer yourself. The question is extremely basic (hence the downvotes). Asking it shows that you have invested very little effort. That is embarassing to you and annoying to us. I was nice and answered anyway -- assuming that you come from, say, C#, it can be a bit puzzling. But be aware that C# made special arrangements for strings, or they would not be "equal" according to `operator==` either! Not any more than any average reference type of your choice.

Comment: In a way the answer should be "you can"; however, the result will not be what you would expect because your comparing pointers, not the characters they point to. =)

Answer (score 4):

A "string" in C is just an array of chars. Comparing two arrays with `==` just compares their addresses, which are different for different arrays. (Literals may or may not be the same, actually, depending on the implementation.)

Comment: I don't think a string in c is just an array of chars is `char string[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};` a string?

Comment: Well, it is an ill-formed string ;-). Let's say that what I said is a true statement about C strings; there are more.

Comment: Yes there are more, good point.